# Swift 5 - System ShareSheet modals' navbar font color is white, blending in with background. How to access their appearance?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

Swift 5, IOS 16, iPad 9.7"

I've got a pretty simple sharesheet implementation to send a pdf file. The share sheet itself looks fine, but "Save to Files" and "Messages" modals all have white font on the nav buttons that make it extremely hard to see. Interestingly, "Email" and "Notes" render fine.

Any ideas? I can't find anything in my app that could affect the system modals' display config.

[ShareSheet looks normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoMre.jpg)

[Email looks normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXPGS.jpg)

[Notes look normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E234t.jpg)

[Messages white font issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIAVu.jpg)

[File Explorer white font issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfDyC.png)

Tried to set

```
UINavigationBar.appearance() = ...
```

but this has no effect no matter what it's set to. Is there a way to capture/examine/debug the modals properties after the sharesheet? I only have visibility into the ShareSheet itself's view controller, not its children:

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
ac.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

Global Accent Color in project settings was set to a white Asset. Removing this config and the asset fixed my issue.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchos-apps/setting-the-app-s-accent-color?changes=_3